# Manga where the MC is a fighter and is rewarded according to his desires

Tags: story-identification, manga

Manga where the MC is summoned as a fighter (demon corps).

MC is rewarded according to what's inside his heart (desires)

- He turns into a monster, fights demons, and gets rewarded.
- When he turns into a monster, he fights with his hands, using raw power.
- His transformation depends on the one riding/controlling him.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SciFi.SE. Please could you go through [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [edit] in any extra details you remember?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: He turns into a monster (fights with his hands) raw power His transformation depends on the one riding/controlling him

Comment: So is the main character a demon? Being possessed by demons? Wear a saddle and being ridden by demons?

Comment: Is he summoned from another world? Within that world? From an afterlife?

Comment: Is this mostly black & white or full colour?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is [*Mato Seihei no Slave*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/116880/Mato_Seihei_no_Slave) also known as *Slave of the Magic Capital's Elite Troops*

In it, the main character falls through a portal to a world of demons. There are women with abilities who fight the demons. One of the women has an ability that lets her command beings to fight for her. The beings that do gain a boost to their powers and she must reward them with something they desire based on what was required of the being. She uses her ability on the main character, which causes him to change forms for the duration of the fight. Afterwards, her body will move on its own to reward him.  She can also let others control him when using the ability, which changes his form based on whoever has control of him.